# How can I force-quit Chrome on Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os

On Chrome OS, Search+Esc brings up the task manager, but the "End Process" button is grayed out for the "Browser" process.

[image: Chrome OS task manager]

If Chrome is still responsive, one could navigate to `chrome://inducebrowsercrashforrealz/`.

But if Chrome is not responsive, is there another way to force quit it?

Answer (score 0):

open a console window.

Use ps -eax |grep chrome

kill -9 ---- where ---- is the pid in the previous result.

Comment: This won't work on Chrome OS because the Linux container is isolated from Chrome.

Comment: I am sorry, I am on an ancient rooted chromebook; where each of the Dalvik processes is a Linux process.